# Declare a string type in a class (C++)

Tags: c++

Here is my file.h :

```
 #define MAXCOMPONENTS 20
 #include <string>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>
 class file{
public:
    file(char const * filename);
    virtual ~file();

    void Takeinfocomponents();
    void Takeshape();

    void Getvalue(int i);
    char *Getcomponents();
    char *Getcolor();


protected:
private:
    char const * filename;
    String shape;
    int value[MAXCOMPONENTS];
    char components[MAXCOMPONENTS];
    char color[MAXCOMPONENTS];

};
```

And my file.cpp :

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <string>
 #include "file.h"
 using namespace std;

 file::file(char const* filename)
 {
     cout << "constructor/fichier:" << filename << endl;
     ifstream fichier(filename,ios::in);
     if(fichier){
         this->filename=filename;
         fichier.close();
         Takeshape();
         Takeinfocomponents();
     }else{
         cout << "File name invalid." << endl;
     }
 }

 file::~file()
 {

 }

 char* file::Getcolor(){
     return this->color;
 }

 char* file::Getcomponents(){
    return this->components;
 }

 void file::Getvalue(int i){
    cout << this->value[i] << endl;
 }


 void file::Takeinfocomponents(){ // pic up name of components, his number and his color
    cout << "Takeinfocomponents/fichier:" << filename << endl;
    ifstream fichier(this->filename,ios::in);
    ifstream stop(this->filename,ios::in);
    string line;
    int i=0;
    getline(fichier,line);
    getline(stop,line);
    getline(stop,line);
    while(line!="/" && i!=99){ // take all informations while the stop signal isn't read
        getline(stop,line);
        fichier >> this->components[i] >> this->value[i] >> this->color[i];
        cout << this->components[i] << this->value[i] << this->color[i] << endl;
        i++;
   }
   fichier.close();
}

void file::Takeshape(){ // pic up the shape in .txt
   cout << "Takeshape" << endl;
   fstream fichier(this->filename,ios::in);
   string shape;
   fichier >> shape;
   this->shape=shape;
   fichier.close();
}
```

This is a part of a larger programm who make graphic from informations ( from the .txt ), this part is use to pic up informations from the .txt.

The problem come from the declaration of the :

```
 String shape;
```

He told me that string is not a name type. I've tried with a small "s" :

```
 string shape;
```

But this ain't working.
I've the impression that i miss a very small things that could unlock my problem.
Thx for help.

Notabene : I'm french and my english is not this good, please answer like i was a little child ahah !

Comment: You probably want `std::string`.

Comment: Just to follow up on @MarkRansom's comment: this is about C++ namespaces. This will give you a good overview: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/namespaces.html

Comment: Whoa thx a lot ! But i do not anderstand why we have to put "std::"

Comment: In addition to the string/String problem, storing a pointer to the filename is a really bad idea. The location it is pointing to is likely to change or go away without notice. Storing the name in another `std::string` is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly state the namespace:

```
std::string shape;
```

You shouldn't pollute the namespace in the headers, so `using namespace std` is not an option here.

See also the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) about namespace pollution. If you just need strings, prefer to use

```
using std::string;
```

in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses the concept of a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace). A namespace is used to group types, variables, etc. together in a meaningful way, regardless of the number of header files those types or variables are spread across.

In this example, the string type is inside the `std` namespace. `std` is short for Standard Template Library, and it is the namespace that most of C++'s library classes, etc. are stored in.

The correct way of accessing type inside a namespace is `namespace::type`, so the correct way of accessing the `string` type inside the `std` namespace is `std::string`. You can also write `using namespace std` to access the types in `std` without having to write `std::` each time, but doing this in a global scope is a bad idea, because it pollutes the global namespace.

In the code you posted, `string shape;` appears before `using namespace std`, as the `#include "file.h"` appears before it. Therefore, it won't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the string class and create string objects, you need to include...

```
#include <string>
```

... at the top of your header files.

You do not need...

```
#include <string.h>
```

The string class, like all STL classes, is part of the std namespace. If you do not want to write std:: before every class name, you can simply state...

```
using namespace std;
```

... at the top of your header files so that instead of...

```
std::string shape;
```

... you can simply use...

```
string shape;
```